# .htaccess keeps asking password at every request

Tags: apache, .htaccess, authentication, .htpasswd

I have a staging website which I protected with a simple .htaccess file.

```
AuthType Basic
AuthName "Please login to access this page"
AuthUserFile /real/path/to/.htpasswd
Require valid-user
```

My .htpasswd is the following:

```
username:hashedpassword
```

When I login from desktop, it works fine (I tried in Firefox, Chrome and Safari).

But when I login from my iPhone (Firefox, Safari), it keeps on asking for login information at every request. It doesn't redirect me if I just dismiss it, but it still keeps on popping every time I make a new request.

I don't know if this is important, but I'm doing in on a subdomain. My .htaccess and .htpasswd files are in the subdirectory that my subdomain is pointing to.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Maybe there's some proxy/firewall in between, which filters the requests.

Comment: @Olaf Dietsche Not that I know of, unfortunately.

Answer (score 1):

I have just come across this problem. After trying to figure it out for the last couple of days I have found out the source of the problem:

This prompt gets triggered when using AuthType Basic and whenever a 401 message is sent from the website.

Is it possible that you had a 401 HTTP status code message being sent from the server at each request?